# Run bge for a certain number of frames?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, keyframes

Is there any way to programmatically specify the number of frames for which you want bge to run? Let's say I want bge to run for 5 frames after which I want to modify some game parameters via some script I have. I'm running everything via command line so accessing any sort of control features via the gui isn't an options. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the frames with a delay sensor:

[image]

Comment: How do I do this with python, though?

Comment: Setting up this logic bricks in Blender or running the BGE?

Comment: setting up the logic bricks above

Comment: It should be possible there is something like bpy.ops.logic.sensor_add(). But I can't help with Blender scripting.